# Ros usage in different type of apps

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use ROS for desktop/mobile app not necessairly to control any robot? I would like to do research on some cool features in ROS and use them in some different type of application(at the beginning for desktop app, later for mobile)? IF possible, any suggestion would be great. Also, If possible, could I have c# app together with ros in c++ code?
I couldnt explain better, because I am not sure if this is possible, so at the moment I dont have any particular app on my mind.

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258226/ros-usage-in-different-type-of-apps/) by [commandos23](https://answers.ros.org/users/24676/commandos23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Ros**'s message exchange principles allow you to implement a many to many computational graph no matter if those nodes a robots or not, those could be sensors, cars, cats or any that is able to implement a pub/subs msg exchange.

If you don't have any particular app on mind, then search for domotic projects, IoT projects, IioT projects  or Industrie projects and try to elaborate a concept that implements data exchange based on ROS.

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0